# Numpy ndarray shape with 3 parameters

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am confused about what is the shape of ndarray when 3 parameters are provided:

For example, what is the difference between:

```
np.zeros((2, 1, 3))
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

and:

```
np.zeros((1, 2, 3))
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

It seems to me that both of them represent 2*3 matrices.

Comment: Dimension 1 is the confusing part here, because you don't see a dimension of one easily. If you try it with (2, 3, 4) you will see the difference immediately. You can always test your numpy arrays with `array.shape`.

Comment: Count the brackets - 3 sets, not 2.  Those convey real information about the array shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the shapes are different, you have to pay attention to the **square brackets**:

```
>>> np.zeros((2, 1, 3))
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

versus:

```
>>> np.zeros((1, 2, 3))
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

as you can see, in the first call, we have two times a pair of square brackets for the second dimension, whereas in the latter, we only have one such pair.

The shape is also different:

```
>>> np.zeros((2, 1, 3)).shape
(2, 1, 3)
>>> np.zeros((1, 2, 3)).shape
(1, 2, 3)
```

So in the former we have a list that contains two sublists. Each of these sublists contains one element: a list of three elements. In the latter we have a list with one element: a sublist with two elements, and these two elements are lists with three elements.

So a *vanilla Python* list equivalent would be:

```
[ [ [0, 0, 0] ], [ [0, 0, 0] ] ]
```

versus:

```
[ [ [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0] ] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

dim=1 is just a dumb dimension, you can alway regard a matrix of `2x3` as a tensor of `1x2x3`.

However, they are technically not the same thing. So you can see the bracket `[]` in your 2 output is not exactly the same, the place of `[]` for the dumb dimension is not at the same position.

For removing dumb dimension, use

```
arr = np.squeeze(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [`numpy.zeros` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), the first argument is a sequence or int representing the shape of the array.

If you look closely the nested square brackets differ in line with the shapes you've built.

This example might make it clearer:

```
np.zeros((2, 3, 4))

array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```